# JpaRepsotory custom query method executes but I can see no record updated in database table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the updatePassword interface which extends the JpaRepository -

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.erecruitment.app.model.user;
@Repository
public interface updatePassword extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
    
    public String nativeQuery="UPDATE user SET password=?1 WHERE username=?2";
    
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value=nativeQuery,nativeQuery=true)
    int updtPassword(String password,String username);  
}
```

After application runs it give the following response in the console -

```
Hibernate: 
    UPDATE
        user 
    SET
        password=? 
    WHERE
        username=?
```

But, the problem is when I check  the database table the values are still same .Also ,there is no error from spring boot . Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That query looks good... maybe the problem somewhere else... Are you sure you connect ot the proper DB? (eg. You made some changes in the properties, or connect Spring connects to an autogenerated inmemory db, etc.)

Comment: I am sure that I am connected at the proper db .No autogenerated in memory db is used as well .